# How to calculate some data based on other data in other collections of mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Imagine there are two collections, `Sessions` and `Students`. Each document in *Sessions collection* represent a day in which students attended the class. There is one field in each document of this collection which is an array named `'students'` - those who attended the class in that particular day. 
And there is Students collection. Each document in this collection represent a student in which there is a field named `'longest_absent_streak'`. This field is a number showing the longest days streak that the student didn't attend the classroom.

How can I update this field in Students collection based on the data from Sessions collections?

p.s. I want it to be updated every time a new Session is created.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will sessions' entry in collection be on daily basis or only on weekdays?meaning attendance of students marked from monday-friday or all days?

Comment: @sushantmehta All days